# Alignment in first row, first column of table generated by DTLforeach

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, datatool

I have a simple table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline\hline
    x & y \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    1 & 4 \\
    2 & 6 \\
    3 & 8 \\
    [1ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: simple table]

I would like to replicate this with `datatool`,
keeping the same horizontal lines and vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{filecontents*}{input.csv}
x,y
1,4
2,6
3,8
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{mytable}{input.csv}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline\hline
    x & y \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    \DTLforeach{mytable}
    {\x=x,\y=y}
    {
      \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}
      \x & \y
    }
    \\
    [1ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is *almost* the same,
but the `1` is misaligned horizontally:

[image: misaligned table]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Avoid `\pagenumbering{gobble}`. If you don't want page numbers, use `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Alright, fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spot the differences:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
x,y
1,4
2,6
3,8
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb{mytable}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c}
    \hline\hline
    x & y \\ [0.5ex]
    \hline
    \DTLforeach{mytable}
    {\x=x,\y=y}
    {%
      \DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}%
      \x & \y
    }
    \\[1ex]
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

No, the position of `filecontents` and the file name are irrelevant. Look for `%`.

You added two spaces with the end-of-lines; the first one is not really relevant, because LaTeX will ignore it, but the one after `\DTLiffirstrow{}{\\}` doesn't get ignored.